# Get Json/Enum values with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, enums, bit-manipulation

What I currently have:

I built html based off options passed into a function to make a list of checkboxes. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/NE5LB/2/

What I need:

I need to determine which box(es) were selected by the user(an alert with correct value would be fine for now).
I set up my list with bitwise format in mind, but havent done much with that in the past.

This maybe a case of me providing too little in terms of code and asking for too much in return. If that is true let me know and I will work on providing more code.

Comment: use some `label` elements for accessibility please.

Comment: Interesting, i just noticed that the elements *are* labels, but they're not reacting normally in the fiddle.

Comment: Actually, they are "lables" (typo), which is why they are not behaving as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) eg:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
      alert(this.id);
    });
  });
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NE5LB/4/) for your updated jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.7+

```
isChecked = $(selector).prop('checked');
```

In jQuery < 1.7

```
isChecked = $(selector).is(':checked');
```